# Config file include issue with sbt native packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

In our project we use multiple configuration files to manage app configurations. 
`application.conf` has `#include "file.conf"` to accomplish it. All files are in the same `universal/conf/` folder.

When I try to run application after `sbt stage`, application fails to find configurations in other conf files except than application.conf

```
No configuration setting found for key 'kafka'
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing
```

It looks like path issue. How can I solve it? Or what's best practice to manage configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your config files are correctly in */conf*, then this is not a native packager issue.

I assume you are using the playframework. By default play looks for an `application.conf`. Under the hood play uses the [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config), which provides multiple ways to override the configuration source. One is to set the resource name

```
config.resource=file.conf
```

Comment: It's not play. But explicitly setting config.resource=application.conf solved the issue. Otherwise it can't find configurations in included file. I don't know it's native packager issue or not though.